# ngIf - loading duplicates on observable with ngFor and async pipe

Tags: angular, meteor, observable, angular-ng-if

I'm using angular2 with meteor.

I've created something like a tabs component where i'm loading some content based on the value of the selected tab. However each time I go between the tabs it loads the data from my service again on top of the old data so I get duplicates..

This is in my component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
      if (this.myTasksSub) {
        this.myTasksSub.unsubscribe();
      }

      this.myTasksSub = MeteorObservable.subscribe('entities').subscribe(() => {
        MeteorObservable.autorun().subscribe(() => {
          this.myTasks = this._entityService.findMyTasks(this.user);
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

and I load it in the standard way in my html:

```
<ul *ngIf="selectedTab==1">
   <li *ngFor="let myTask of myTasks | async">
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like a lot of nested subscribes... Anyway, there is some chance the issue comes from your service class. It would definitely help to include it in your question.

Comment: if your tabs component destroys invisible tabs and reloads them, then when the async pipe is relaoded, it will resubscribe to myTasks